# In MySQL, Is SUBSTRING(1, 200) better than fetching the full value of a TEXT column?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, query-optimization, substring

Say you have a TEXT column on your table which could either be huge / paragraph long rants, or only a few sentence long lines.

Performance wise / server load wise, is it better to do:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING( myTxtColumn, 1, 200) FROM myTable AS myTxtColumn
```

Or to do:

```
SELECT myTxtColumn FROM myTable
```

Which of the queries puts more load on the server?

I'm curious if it will be easier for the server to fetch the full value of the column than doing a SUBSTRING() on it, or if the SUBSTRING() will be easier since its only returning the first 200 chars rather than the several KB long text values.

Comment: cpu versus network traffic (possibly disk I/O as well, but should be cached in memory if hot pages); suggest you benchmark....

Comment: i guess no differences for both as both also required disk seek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd err on the side of caution and use the substring.  Your first query **may** need to read the whole string before doing substring on it (I suspect mysql is smarter than that, but who knows).  Your second query **definitely** has to read the whole string and send it over the network.